# Trying to swtich the value of an variable-Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, html

So I need to switch the turns of "X" and "O" using the changeturns function in the game, but the code I have can only produce "O". I know there are some similar questions but the way of writing the code is too different to compare.

[the code so far](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ktabley-carrayion?path=script.js:50:1)  FROM AN ONLINE TUTORIAL

Comment: why don't you make the `newplayer` variable global?

Comment: Hi, I tried , still doesn't work. Maybe the way I set it is wrong.

Comment: Putting the solution link here too: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mesquite-knuckle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and mutatue the variable from within the function declaration. Instead, return the new value and assign it to the target player.

```
var player = 'X'

function changeturns(newplayer){
 if(newplayer=='O'){
    return 'X';
  } else {
    return 'O';
  }
}

// reassign the value returned to the variable: 
player = changeturns(player)
console.log(player); // changed to 'O'
```

Primitive values in JavaScript are immutable. When you pass the value into the function, the reference isn't passed, only the value from the reference. It would work the player was an object that contained a `turn` property. However, it's generally recommended that mutations not occur on items passed into functions. Instead, you should determine how the value should be modified, then directly modify them from within the same scope.

Comment: Hi, I tried, still doesn't work. may I ask why put player = changeturns(player) outside the function?

Comment: I put player = changeturns(player) outside of the function because that's the correct way of assigning values to variables in JS. The function I gave you works as expected, returning an 'O' or 'X' string. you then assign that value to the variable you want outside of the function because the scope inside the function doesn't have access to the reference, only the value the reference was pointing to.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I am still confused. After trying out both of your methods I am still not switching the player. Could you have a look again?

Comment: I can if you change your question to include the HTML

Comment: Oh, I see the HTML now. I've never used that IDE, give me a minute.

Comment: @JiangYuxin There are several things I changed in your code to get it working. The first was to declare the player variable within the scope of the startGame function. Then, this could be directly reassigned and used to determine which letter to draw. I've modified your code and made a new working snippet here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mesquite-knuckle

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure and am currently trying to find out, but having the parameter named the same as your global var `newplayer` is causing the issue. The other issue was your `script.js` is included twice causing two click handlers to be registered for each cell.

```
var gameboard = [];
var theplayer = "O";
var friendplayer = "X";
var newplayer = "X";
var winningcombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [6, 4, 2]
];
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
startGame();

function startGame() {
  document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
  gameboard = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].innerText = " ";
    cells[i].style.removeProperty("backgroung-color");
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", turnclick);
  }
}

function turnclick(event) {
  turn(event.target.id, newplayer);
}

function turn(squareId, p) {
  gameboard[squareId] = p;
  document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = p;
  changeturns(p);
}

function changeturns(p) {
  if (newplayer == "O") {
    newplayer = "X";
  } else {
    newplayer = "O";
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. My answer gives half, yours gives the other. If he takes my advice (refraining from external variable mutations within a function) then removes the double event assignment that you pointed out, his problem will be solved.